# Filter data from Room

Tags: android, android-room

I have the database Room in which there are fields day and month (past date, present and future)
How can I show data only of the present time and the future?
That is, take the current date and somehow take the data from the database only equal to this date or exceeding

Comment: You could get an instance of a new Date object and convert it to a timestamp in milliseconds, then convert the dates from the database to timestamps as well and do a simple comparison. If currentDate <= databaseDate... blah blah blah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have to store day/month as separate columns? It could be easier to store the date as long ([Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)))

```
@Entity
public class Model {
    @PrimaryKey
    private final long id;

    private final long dateMls;

    //...
}

@Dao
public interface ModelDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Model WHERE dateMls >= :currentTimeMls")
    List<Model> getCurrentAndFuture(long currentTimeMls);
}
```

Comment: Exactle Epoch. Thanks))